# Relationship between subspace and orthogonal complement over a field of positive characteristic

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, inner-products

I'm looking at practice problems for a PhD exam, and I'm uncertain on how to approach the last part of this one.

Let $V$ be $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the standard inner product. For an arbitrary subspace $U$  of $V$, let $U^\perp = \{v \in V | \langle u,v \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } u \in U\}$.

(a) Show that $U \cap U^\perp = \{0\}$
(b) Show that $U \oplus U^\perp = V$
(c) Show that $(U^\perp)^\perp = U$
(d) Which of these statements remain true over a field of positive characteristic?

I was able to answer parts (a)-(c) just fine. I'm uncertain about part (d). I know that a field of characteristic is a field such that $n \bullet 1 = 0$ , for some positive integer $n$. I don't know how that would affect any of the above results. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: I recommend going back at your proofs and seeing where you used the fact that the characteristic was $0$. For example, I imagine you used the characteristic-$0$ inequality $v_1^2+\cdots+v_n^2\ge0$ to conclude (a); how does that break in positive characteristic? Think about $v=(1,1,\dots,1)$ for example.

Comment: @GregMartin Right, $\langle v,v \rangle = 0$ under the analogous definition (assuming the characteristic is $n$), but then this is no longer an inner product.